# RecoilJS with RNN

Tags: react-native-navigation, recoiljs

Facebook's new RecoilJS is gaining traction as an amazing state management tool with great potential, but how can we use it with RNN if we need to wrap the root view with RecoilRoot. Is there a way to wrap the root view of a RNN app?

```
import {RecoilRoot} from 'recoil';

function AppRoot() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <SomeRootView />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using it like this and it seems to be working fine.

```
import {RecoilRoot} from 'recoil';

function AppRoot() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <RecoilRoot>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <BottomNav />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </RecoilRoot>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: you are not using RNN, the problem is with RNN.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I found this post while searching for help with Recoil and  React Navigation in a React Native app, I see now that RNN is a different from React Navigation, sorry for the confusion

Comment: No problem, RNN's problem is that every screen is a root. I solved with by simply having different root states, it can work for now.